If $\phi:A\to B$ is a positive map of $C^*$-algebras and $e$ a projection such that $\phi(e) = \phi(1)$ then $\phi(a) = \phi(eae)$ for all $a ≥ 0$.
I am trying to understand the proof of the following statement:
Let $\phi: A \rightarrow B$ be a positive map, $A$ and $B$ being $C^{*}$-algebras. If $e$ is an orthogonal projection in $A$ such that $\phi(e)=\phi(1)$, then the restriction of $\phi$ to $e A e$ is an extremal map e $A e \rightarrow B$ if and only if $\phi$ is extremal.
The proof is clear to me, except the following statement:
"If $0 \leq a \in A$ then, since $\phi(a)=\phi(e a e)$ from the assumption on $\phi$..."
What it essentially amounts to showing is that if $\phi$ is a positive map such that $\phi(e) = \phi(1)$, then $\phi(a)=\phi(e a e)$ for all $a \geq 0$.  I am clueless on how to proceed to show this result. Moreover, do we even need the condition that $a$ is positive? Any suggestions or hints are welcome.

This is essentially Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, and no, $a$ being positive is not needed. Indeed, let $\psi$ be any state on $B$. Then $(x,y) \mapsto \psi(\phi(x^\ast y))$ is a positive sesquilinear form on $A$, so by Cauchy-Schwarz,
$$\begin{split}
|\psi(\phi((1-e)a))| &\leq |\psi(\phi(|1-e|^2))|^{1/2} |\psi(\phi(|a|^2))|^{1/2}\\
&= |\psi(\phi(1-e))|^{1/2} |\psi(\phi(|a|^2))|^{1/2}\\
&= 0
\end{split}$$
where the final equality follows from $\phi(e) = \phi(1)$ so $\phi(1-e) = 0$. Since this holds for all state $\psi$, we have $\phi((1-e)a) = 0$ and thus $\phi(a) = \phi(ea)$.
Similarly,
$$|\psi(\phi(a(1-e)))| \leq |\psi(\phi(|a^\ast|^2))|^{1/2}|\psi(\phi(|1-e|^2))|^{1/2} = 0$$
So again we have $\phi(a(1-e)) = 0$ and thus $\phi(a) = \phi(ae)$. Combining the two results together yields,
$$\phi(a) = \phi(ae) = \phi(eae)$$

Thank you so much! Another approach is to just consider, WLOG, $B \subset B(H)$ for some Hilbert space $H$, so that we know exactly what the positive functionals look like, essentially given by $b \to \langle \xi, b\xi \rangle$, $\xi \in H$. This is an identical approach, relying on the GNS-theorem.
